# Boot from nvme ssd in Jetson Nano periodically fails

Tags: boot, 20.04, ssd, services

I have followed instructions from [this link](https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2020/06/22/boot-jetson-xavier-from-m-2-ssd/) in order to make my Jetson Nano custom board boot from nvme ssd disk.

It is working most of the time. But, sometimes, after reboot the service responsible for performing the task fails.

I get the following message:

```
$ systemctl status setssdroot.service
```

> ● setssdroot.service - Change rootfs to SSD in M.2 key M slot
> (nvme0n1p1) Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/setssdroot.service;
> enabled; vendor preset: enabled) Active: inactive (dead) Condition:
> start condition failed at Wed 2023-11-22 08:01:45 +04; 8h ago
> └─ ConditionPathExists=/dev/nvme0n1p1 was not met

Any idea what might be causing the issue?

P.S. This is the code of setssdroot.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Change rootfs to SSD in M.2 key M slot (nvme0n1p1)
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target
After=systemd-remount-fs.service
Before=local-fs-pre.target local-fs.target shutdown.target
Wants=local-fs-pre.target
ConditionPathExists=/dev/nvme0n1p1
ConditionPathExists=/etc/setssdroot.conf
ConditionVirtualization=!container
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/sbin/setssdroot.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* earlier this year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Comment: @guiverc I have modified the tag, the issue is not directly related to a specific Ubuntu version.